# Get file list and file size in one go with Python?

Tags: python, file, filesystems

I need to get a list of files with their respective size. An obvious way to do it is to use `os.listdir()`, then loop over the results with `os.path.getsize()`. This can be achieved in a simple one-liner:

For instance:

```py
In [1]: import os

In [2]: files = {f:os.path.getsize(f) for f in os.listdir()}
```

I was wondering if there's a more clever way to do this (e.g. if there's a standard method that already does it in one shot)?

In the end, what I want to do is use `tqdm` to show progress as I loop over files, based on their size (but I still need to figure out how that works!).

Comment: Given that in Unix, `readdir` and `stat` are separate system calls, my guess would be "no".  But someone more cleverer might know something.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single command `stat` in my zsh:

```
import os
files = dict([x.split() for x in os.popen('stat -f "%z %N" *').read().split("\n")[:-1]])
```

Certainly more dirty but still does in it one system call to the operating system.

Comment: That's essentially doing the same thing as the original Python code.  The `*` is "glob"bed by the shell by reading the directory.  The expanded list is then given to `stat`, where it gets info on each file.